# Strip time from an object date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with some dates from zipped xlsx files. These files are loaded into a sqlite database then exported as .csv. Each file is about 40,000 rows per day. The issue I run into is that `pd.to_datetime` does not seem to work on these objects (dates from Excel format is causing the issue I think - pure .csv files work fine with this command). This is fine actually - I do not need them to be in datetime format.

What I am trying to achieve is creating a column called ShortDate which is `%m/%d/%Y`. How can I do this on a datetime object (format is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss from Excel). I will then create a new column called RosterID which combines the EmployeeID field and the ShortDate field together into a unique ID.

I am very new to pandas and I am currently only using it to process .csv files (rename and select certain columns, create unique IDs to use in filters in Tableau, etc).

```
rep = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv.gz', dtype = 'str', compression = 'gzip', usecols = ['etc','etc2'])
print('Read successfully.')
rep['Total']=1
rep['UniqueID']= rep['EmployeeID'] + rep['InteractionID']
rep['ShortDate'] = ??? #what do I do here to get what I am looking for?
rep['RosterID']= rep['EmployeeID'] + rep['ShortDate'] # this is my goal
print('Modified successfully.')
```

Here is some of the raw data from the .csv. Column names would be

```
InteractionID, Created Date, EmployeeID, Repeat Date
07927,04/01/2014 14:05:10,912a,04/01/2014 14:50:03
02158,04/01/2014 13:44:05,172r,04/04/2014 17:47:29
44279,04/01/2014 17:28:36,217y,04/07/2014 22:06:19
```

Comment: Please show a few lines of your data, preferably cut-and-pasteable

Comment: I added 3 rows of the data. I want a 04/07/2014 (object) result in a column called 'ShortDate'. I will then combine that data and the Employee ID into a new column called RosterID (I will use that to determine who was managing the agent at a particular time, etc, from a roster database).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new column, then just apply simple `datetime` functions using `lambda` and `apply`.

```
In [14]: df['Short Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date'])

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   InteractionID    Created Date EmployeeID     Repeat Date  \
0           7927  4/1/2014 14:05       912a  4/1/2014 14:50   
1           2158  4/1/2014 13:44       172r  4/4/2014 17:47   
2          44279  4/1/2014 17:28       217y  4/7/2014 22:06   

           Short Date  
0 2014-04-01 14:05:00  
1 2014-04-01 13:44:00  
2 2014-04-01 17:28:00  

In [16]: df['Short Date'] = df['Short Date'].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%m%d%y'))

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   InteractionID    Created Date EmployeeID     Repeat Date Short Date  
0           7927  4/1/2014 14:05       912a  4/1/2014 14:50     040114   
1           2158  4/1/2014 13:44       172r  4/4/2014 17:47     040114   
2          44279  4/1/2014 17:28       217y  4/7/2014 22:06     040114
```

Then just concatenate the two columns. Convert the `Short Date` column to strings to avoid errors on concatenation of strings and integers.

```
In [32]: df['Roster ID'] = df['EmployeeID'] + df['Short Date'].map(str)

In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
   InteractionID    Created Date EmployeeID     Repeat Date Short Date  \
0           7927  4/1/2014 14:05       912a  4/1/2014 14:50     040114   
1           2158  4/1/2014 13:44       172r  4/4/2014 17:47     040114   
2          44279  4/1/2014 17:28       217y  4/7/2014 22:06     040114   

    Roster ID  
0  912a040114  
1  172r040114  
2  217y040114
```

Comment: ValueError: year=1 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900

I get that error on the strftime line for some reason. Any ideas? The dates range from April 01 - April 30 2014

Comment: That error should only occur if you have a date whose year is below 1900. Otherwise, `strftime` is smart enough to convert it as shown above without errors. Are you sure your values are correct? Try exporting to CSV right before doing the `apply`. A date might have been incorrectly converted from `Created Date`.

Comment: I see that some (actually just 1 in April) row has blank values in the date. This defaults to a Null or year 1899 datetime. 

Is there a quick way to not read the rows with a blank value for InteractionID or Date?

Comment: I am trying this

df = df[pd.notnull(df['Created Date'])]

Seems to be working. Is there a command to drop the rows where the date is not a date? My fear would be that a row would have a different value (like an EmployeeID) in the date column which would make it seem like it was not null.

Comment: You can always just index out the line where the date is `NaN` or something. Depends really on your case, but you can do something like `df[df['Created Date'] != np.Nan` or a variation thereof.

Answer (score 12):

You can apply a post-processing step that first converts the string to a datetime and then applies a lambda to keep just the date portion:

```
In [29]:

df['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date']).apply(lambda x: x.date())
df['Repeat Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Repeat Date']).apply(lambda x: x.date())
df


Out[29]:
   InteractionID Created Date EmployeeID Repeat Date
0           7927   2014-04-01       912a  2014-04-01
1           2158   2014-04-01       172r  2014-04-04
2          44279   2014-04-01       217y  2014-04-07
```

**EDIT**

After looking at this again, you can access just the date component using `dt.date` if your version of pandas is greater than `0.15.0`:

```
In [18]:
df['just_date'] = df['Repeat Date'].dt.date
df

Out[18]:
   InteractionID        Created Date EmployeeID         Repeat Date  \
0           7927 2014-04-01 14:05:10       912a 2014-04-01 14:50:03   
1           2158 2014-04-01 13:44:05       172r 2014-04-04 17:47:29   
2          44279 2014-04-01 17:28:36       217y 2014-04-07 22:06:19   

    just_date  
0  2014-04-01  
1  2014-04-04  
2  2014-04-07
```

Additionally you can also do `dt.strftime` now rather than use `apply` to achieve the result you want:

```
In [28]:
df['short_date'] = df['Repeat Date'].dt.strftime('%m%d%Y')
df

Out[28]:
   InteractionID        Created Date EmployeeID         Repeat Date  \
0           7927 2014-04-01 14:05:10       912a 2014-04-01 14:50:03   
1           2158 2014-04-01 13:44:05       172r 2014-04-04 17:47:29   
2          44279 2014-04-01 17:28:36       217y 2014-04-07 22:06:19   

    just_date short_date  
0  2014-04-01   04012014  
1  2014-04-04   04042014  
2  2014-04-07   04072014
```

So generating the Roster Id's is now a trivial exercise of adding the 2 new columns:

```
In [30]:
df['Roster ID'] = df['EmployeeID'] + df['short_date']
df

Out[30]:
   InteractionID        Created Date EmployeeID         Repeat Date  \
0           7927 2014-04-01 14:05:10       912a 2014-04-01 14:50:03   
1           2158 2014-04-01 13:44:05       172r 2014-04-04 17:47:29   
2          44279 2014-04-01 17:28:36       217y 2014-04-07 22:06:19   

    just_date short_date     Roster ID  
0  2014-04-01   04012014  912a04012014  
1  2014-04-04   04042014  172r04042014  
2  2014-04-07   04072014  217y04072014
```

Comment: That worked. When I tried to make a RosterID column (EmployeeID + Created Date) I received an error but I was able to fix it by making the Created Date .astype(str).

Would it be better to make a hierarchical index with Created Date and EmployeeID rather than combining them physically in another column?

Comment: Up to you, depends on what each record really means

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using only the standard libraries (in any format you want '%m/%d/%Y', '%m-%d-%Y' or other orders/formats):

```
In [118]:

import time
df['Created Date'] = df['Created Date'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')))
In [120]:

print df
   InteractionID Created Date EmployeeID          Repeat Date
0           7927   04/01/2014       912a  04/01/2014 14:50:03
1           2158   04/01/2014       172r  04/04/2014 17:47:29
2          44279   04/01/2014       217y  04/07/2014 22:06:19
```